# WPF Binding Reference actual item of datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have This clases

```
public class Class1
{
    public int Class1Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public partial class Class2
{
    public Class2()
    {
        this.Class3 = new HashSet<Class3>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Class1Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Class1 Class1{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Class3> Class3 { get; set; }

}

public partial class Class3
{
    public int Class3Id { get; set; }
    public int OtherProp { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then on a viewmodel I have an observabel collection of class2

```
ObservableCollection<Class2> MyColl = new ObservableCollection<Class2>();
```

THis Observable is Binded to a grid as this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DatGridPlanillas" ItemsSource="{Binding MyColl,Mode=TwoWay}" 
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Class1 Description" Binding="{Binding /Class1.Description}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Class2 Id" Binding="{Binding Id ,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Class2 Descriprion" Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

My problem is Class1.Description never Show and at results panel on VS there is a message that show

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Class1' property not found on 'current item of collection' ''Class2_D0FAA12D4E698EE37B64760A79763EA5E957BAC04F8E9FED7BDA4B99892A712D' (HashCode=61628235)'. BindingExpression:Path=/Class1.Description; DataItem='Class2_D0FAA12D4E698EE37B64760A79763EA5E957BAC04F8E9FED7BDA4B99892A712D' (HashCode=61628235); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

All other properties are rendered as  I expect.

Whats causing this problem?

Comment: What do you mean with actual item? There is no actual item in Class2. Remove the `/` in `Binding="{Binding /Class1.Description}` and it should show the description.

Comment: Tks for your help nothing this throw this another error ystem.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Class1' property not found on 'object' ''Class2_D0FAA12D4E698EE37B64760A79763EA5E957BAC04F8E9FED7BDA4B99892A712D' (HashCode=41412514)'. BindingExpression:Path=Class1.Description; DataItem='Class2_D0FAA12D4E698EE37B64760A79763EA5E957BAC04F8E9FED7BDA4B99892A712D' (HashCode=41412514); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a typo in your binding.

Change your Binding to the following:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Class1 Description" Binding="{Binding Path=Class1.Description}"/>
```

or

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Class1 Description" Binding="{Binding Class1.Description}"/>
```

This worked for me when I tried your example.

Comment: Excelent at least two hours Fighting with this.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help :-)